# Find and Replace missing value

Tags: r

The embarked column has missing values. I am trying to find the missing value and replace it with S.

See below for an example. This may be simple but I am new to R Studio and would appreciate any help. Also below is the code I attempted to use.

```
embarked    boat
             2
            11
S   
S   
S   
             3
S
```

Code

```
blanks <- (" " = "S")

titantic_original1 <- blanks[titanic_original$embarked]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
titanic_original$embarked <- with(titanic_original, replace(embarked, embarked=="", "S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
titanic_original$embarked[is.na(titanic_original$embarked)] <- "S"
```

Comment: The code above replaced the missing values in the "boat" column as well. Is there a way to find and replace the missing values with the letter "S" in the "embarked" column only?

Comment: I fixed my code now. It wasn't clear to me that you only wanted to replace the missing values in the `embarked` column. You might want to edit your main question to reflect it.